# Why is width:min-content still overflowing?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am bewildered by the behavior of min-content in CSS. Here is a minimal reproducible example (with tailwind)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen w-screen">
  <p class="h-full w-min border-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo. Massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at. Tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus.
    </p>
</div>
```

Expected behavior: The p element should size its width large enough to avoid vertical overflow. This is not the case, it is not wide enough and the text is overflowing. What am I missing?

Edit: The original goal was to have text take up as much vertical space as possible, without overflowing, and size it horizontally. Maybe there's a way to achieve this with flexbox or something like that, but min-content doesn't seem to be the way.

Comment: its width is as small as its content will possibly allow - this _doesn't_ necessarily mean it will _never_ overflow ever. perhaps also have a look at `max-content` or `fit-content`, they might fit your needs as well

Comment: It's overflowing vertically, not horizontally. Why would you expect width to prevent vertical overflow?

Comment: [min-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content) pertains to element width only, and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I saw this quote "According to the W3C specifications, the min-content is the smallest size a box can take without overflowing its content." and I assumed it covered overflow in both directions. I now see that this would only prevent x axis overflow

Comment: For text content `width: min-content` means that the content will take all soft-wrapping opportunities, becoming as small as the longest word. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having a similar problem right now...

Answer (score 0):

- Use `min-h-full` to fit the height to the content. See [min-height](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height)
- As pointed out in [@md-rakibul-islam's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11037185/md-rakibul-islam) comment use `style="width:min-content"` to set width to the longest word. [min-content MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content)
- Here is your lorem ipsum and a smaller text example to show it

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="w-screen">
  <p class="min-h-full border-4" style="width:min-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo. Massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at. Tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus.
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="w-screen">
  <p class="min-h-full border-4" style="width:min-content">
        Less content in this one
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't exactly what I wanted: My goal was to have multi-line text take up as much vertical space as possible and as little horizontal space as possible. I'm not sure if there's any way to accomplish this, but it looks like min-content isn't the way

Comment: Sorry that's my fault! I think this is what you are looking more for?